# Code coverage in vs 2010

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

We just switched over to VS2010, and I remember a while back I had setup code coverage for a project I was working on in 2010, and there being a little bit of setup involved. I can't seem to remember the steps in wiring up code coverage with my unit test results. Anyone know the steps?

Comment: Have you already chosen a code coverage framework to use? Do you want to use the one built into VS? Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: I have VS 2010 Ultimate, and I'll be using the build in tools

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx

got me just what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN article: [How to: Obtain Code Coverage Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182496.aspx). Note that this feature is only available in the Team editions of visual studio.